# Llamar una constante de una función asíncrona desde un useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Tengo un componente en el que dentro de un mismo useEffect hago una petición fetch y luego filtro los datos. Para ello, la respuesta la guardo en una variable data y para poder operar con esta data sin perder mis datos originales, he creado otra variable llamada operationData en la que guardo ese data inicial. Sin embargo, por cuestiones de rendimiento no puedo mantener ambas cosas dentro del mismo useEffect.
He pensado en sacar la petición fetch fuera del useEffect pero tengo un problema de comunicación, y es que a la hora de crear operationData dentro del useEffect no me reconoce el data que está fuera en una función asíncrona para poder hacer el fetch.

Por ejemplo, yo en mi componente tengo dentro de un componente:

```
let data = response.json();
```

Y dentro de un useEffect quiero hacer la copia de ese data para poder operar con él, y tengo:

```
var operationData = data;
```

¿Cómo hago para indicarle al operationData de dentro del useEffect que quiero tomar el data de fuera?

Comment: Estas usando estados para manejar esos datos??

Comment: No, la respuesta del fetch la guardo en  un let

Comment: Una de las características de React es que de basa en estados para manejar los datos. Si estás usando React, la idea es que entiendas la forma en la que funciona para poder sacar el mejor provecho a la librería. Podrías comenzar investigando sobre useState para que tengas más contexto.

Comment: No puedo usar estados porque tengo unas gráficas que renderizan lo primero que leen de este componente en el que tengo problemas y pintan lo primero que leen, si declaro un estado me va a sacar null y no me va a coger los datos. Necesito llamar ese data que está dentro de un useEffect desde el operationData que está en otro useEffect diferente dentro del mismo componente.

Comment: Insisto, la problemática se puede / debe resolver con estados. Por eso estás usando React. Podrías declarar un estado inicial y dentro de tu useEffect pasarle los valores a dicho estado para que sean renderizados al momento de levantarse el componente

Comment: Te comprendo, pero es que mi gráfica renderizan lo primero que leen y si leen que data es nulo, les da igual que luego le actualice con el response.json().

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez simplemente puedes declarar desde un principio:

```
var operationData = null;
```

Luego puedes hacer en el useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  operationData = response.json(); // También puedes intentar con this.operationData solo si tienes un error
});
```

Espero poder ayudarte.

Comment: No puedo hacerle eso porque tengo un hijo de ese componente que renderiza una gráfica con clases, y de la primera barrida ya me lee los datos y pinta la grafía. El problema es que la respuesta del json está en un useEffect y en otro useEffect debajo del primero tengo que llamar al data que guarda la respuesta del json. No reconoce si declaro data en el primer useEffect y llamo data en el segundo useEffect